# jQuery - Escape special chars in anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, scroll, decode

I am having some trouble with a smooth scrolling function. The anchors have special characters (åäö) in them, but when getting `$(this.hash)` they are encoded, thus giving me a `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #sp%C3%A5r1`  (where the anchor links to #spår1).

How can I prevent the encoding to make them link to the right id? I tried to decodeURI but to no avail, since the error is thrown by jQuery in the statement before (`var target = $(this.hash)`)

This is the code:

```
$('a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') ||
  location.hostname == this.hostname) {

  var navHeight = 0;
  if (document.querySelector('#nav')) {
    navHeight = document.querySelector('#nav').offsetHeight;
  }

//GET HASH FROM ANCHOR

  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = decodeURI(target);

  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top - navHeight
    }, 100);
    return false;
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Wrong order. Try: `var target = $(decodeURI(this.hash))`. Or even better, find whoever set `this.hash` and fix it there.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! Did you mean the people who set the hash-values? That is above my head haha so have to work around it!